# Display table values in new window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html-table

EDIT:
Ok I found why it was not working. Jquery was ok but instead of value I took text, so instead .val just .text

So I have a little problem here.

I have a task to export outlook contact file and import it to a database, then display it in html table.

*So I did that already and it was not that hard, but here is the next task:*

I have my table, with a lot of rows and cells. My first cell is "**First Name**". When the user clicks on any of the "**First Name**" to open new window and create input **textarea** with the **value of that cell**.

So for example when I click on the name "**Georgi**" new window should popup with new **textarea** with the name "**Georgi**". When I click on "**Tomas**" new window should popup with new **textarea** with the name "**Tomas**". So this textarea should be universal for all names.

I mean I did it for only one name, but do not know how to do it for all names.

I hope you understood me what I want. Here is a picture of the table:

[image: image:]

**code:**

```
<table id = "firstname" border="2" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" width="10000" >
<tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Middle Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Suffix</th>
        <th>Company</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>Job Title</th>
        <th>Business Street</th>
        <th>Business Street 2</th>
        <th>Business Street 3</th>
        <th>Business City</th>
        <th>Business State</th>
        <th>Business Postal Code</th>
        <th>Business Country/Region</th>
        <th>Home Street</th> 
        <th>Home Street 2</th>
        <th>Home Street 3</th>
        <th>Home City</th>
        <th>Home State</th>
        <th>Home Postal Code</th>
        <th>Home Country Region</th>
        <th>Other Street</th>
        <th>Other Street 2</th>
        <th>Other Street 3</th>
        <th>Other City</th>
        <th>Other State</th>
        <th>Other Postal Code</th>
        <th>Other Country/Region</th>
        <th>Assistant's Phone</th>
        <th>Business Fax</th>
        <th>Business Phone</th>
        <th>Business Phone 2</th>
        <th>Callback</th>
        <th>Car Phone</th>
        <th>Company Main Phone</th>
        <th>Home Fax</th>
        <th>Home Phone</th>
        <th>Home Phone 2</th>
        <th>ISDN</th>
        <th>Mobile Phone</th>
        <th>Other Fax</th>
        <th>Other Phone</th>
        <th>Pager</th>
        <th>Primary Phone</th>
        <th>Radio Phone</th>
        <th>TTY/TDD PHone</th>
        <th>Telex</th>
        <th>Account</th>
        <th>Anniversary</th>
        <th>Assistant's Name</th>
        <th>Billing Information</th>
        <th>Birthday</th>
        <th>Business Address PO Box</th>
        <th>Categories</th>
        <th>Children</th>
        <th>Directory Server</th>      
        <th>Email Address</th>
        <th>Email Type</th>
        <th>Email Display Name</th>
        <th>Email Address 2</th>
        <th>Email Type 2</th>
        <th>Email Display Name 2</th>
        <th>Email Address 3</th>
        <th>Email Type 3</th>
        <th>Email Display Name 3</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Government ID Number</th>
        <th>Hobby</th>
        <th>Home Address PO Box</th>
        <th>Initials</th>
        <th>Internet Free/Busy</th>
        <th>Keywords</th>
        <th>Language</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Manager's Name</th>
        <th>Mileage</th>
        <th>Notes</th>
        <th>Office Location</th>
        <th>Organizational ID Number</th>
        <th>Other Address PO Box</th>
        <th>Priority</th>
        <th>Private</th>
        <th>Profession</th>
        <th>Referred By</th>
        <th>Sensitivity</th>
</tr>

<tr class='table_row'>
        <?php

        mysqli_select_db($con,'outlook');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM contacts";
    $myData = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

    while($record =  mysqli_fetch_array($myData))
    {

        echo "<tr>";


        echo "<td id=\"fname\">" . "<a class='why' href='#'  onClick='myFunction()'>" . $record['first_name'] . "</a>" . "</td>";
        echo '<script type="text/javascript">';

        echo 'function myFunction(){';


        echo 'var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=1024, height=555, left=450, top=100");';

        echo 'myWindow.document.write(';
        echo '"';
        echo '<html>';
        echo '<head>';
        echo '<script src=\"http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js\"><\/script>'; 

        echo '<script type=\"text/javascript\">';



        echo '<\/script>';
        echo '</head>';
        echo '<body>';

        echo '<div id=\"showcase\" style=\"background-color: #F5FFE0;  margin-right: 25%; margin-left: 30%; padding-left:3%; padding-right:2%; border:solid 5px #242222;\">';

        echo '<p style=\"background-color:#7A993D;\">Personal</p>';
        echo '<select>';
        echo '<option  selected >Full Name</option>';
        echo '</select>';
        echo '<input type=\"text\" value=\"'.($record['first_name']).'\" style=\"margin-left: 25.3%;\"><br>';

        echo '<select>';
        echo '<option  selected>Company</option>';
        echo '</select>';
        echo '<input type=\"text\" value=\"'.($record['company']).'\" style=\"margin-left: 26.3%;\"><br>';

        echo '<select>';
        echo '<option  selected>Job Title</option>';
        echo '</select>';

        echo '<input type=\"text\" value=\"'.($record['job_title']).'\" style=\"margin-left: 28%;\"><br><br>';

        echo '<p style=\"background-color:#7A993D;\">Internet</p>';
        echo '<select>';
        echo '<option>E-Mail</option>';
        echo '<option>E-Mail 2</option>';
        echo '<option>E-Mail 3</option>';
        echo '</select>';
        echo '<input type=\"text\" value=\"'.($record['email_address']).'\" style=\"margin-left: 28%;\"><br>';

        echo '<select>';
        echo '<option  selected>Web page address</option>';
        echo '</select>';
        echo '<input type=\"text\" value=\"'.($record['internet_free_busy']).'\" style=\"margin-left: 12.5%;\"><br>';
        echo '<p style=\"background-color:#7A993D;\">Phone numbers</p>';            
        echo '<select>';
        echo '<option>Assistant</option>';
        echo '<option  selected>Business</option>';
        echo '<option>Business 2</option>';
        echo '<option>Business Fax</option>';
        echo '<option>Callback</option>';
        echo '<option>Car</option>';
        echo '<option>Company</option>';
        echo '<option>Home</option>';
        echo '<option>Home 2</option>';
        echo '<option>Home Fax</option>';
        echo '<option>ISDN</option>';
        echo '<option>Mobile</option>';
        echo '<option>Other</option>';
        echo '<option>Other Fax</option>';
        echo '<option>Pager</option>';
        echo '<option>Primary</option>';
        echo '<option>Radio</option>';
        echo '<option>Telex</option>';
        echo '<option>TTY/TDD</option>';
        echo '</select>';
        echo '<script>';
        echo 'var myColor = document.getElementById(\"fname\").value;';
        echo '<\/script>';
        echo '<input type=\"text\" value=myColor style=\"margin-left: 20%;\"><br>';
        echo '<select>';
        echo '<option>Assistant</option>';
        echo '<option selected>Business</option>';
        echo '<option>Business 2</option>';
        echo '<option>Business Fax</option>';
        echo '<option>Callback</option>';
        echo '<option>Car</option>';
        echo '<option>Company</option>';
        echo '<option>Home</option>';
        echo '<option>Home 2</option>';
        echo '<option>Home Fax</option>';
        echo '<option>ISDN</option>';
        echo '<option>Mobile</option>';
        echo '<option>Other</option>';
        echo '<option>Other Fax</option>';
        echo '<option>Pager</option>';
        echo '<option>Primary</option>';
        echo '<option>Radio</option>';
        echo '<option>Telex</option>';
        echo '<option>TTY/TDD</option>';
        echo '</select>';
        echo '<input type=\"text\" value=\"'.($record['business_phone']).'\" style=\"margin-left: 20%;\"><br>';
                    echo '<select>';
        echo '<option>Assistant</option>';
        echo '<option>Business</option>';
        echo '<option>Business 2</option>';
        echo '<option selected>Business Fax</option>';
        echo '<option>Callback</option>';
        echo '<option>Car</option>';
        echo '<option>Company</option>';
        echo '<option>Home</option>';
        echo '<option>Home 2</option>';
        echo '<option>Home Fax</option>';
        echo '<option>ISDN</option>';
        echo '<option>Mobile</option>';
        echo '<option>Other</option>';
        echo '<option>Other Fax</option>';
        echo '<option>Pager</option>';
        echo '<option>Primary</option>';
        echo '<option>Radio</option>';
        echo '<option>Telex</option>';
        echo '<option>TTY/TDD</option>';
        echo '</select>';
        echo '<input type=\"text\" value=\"'.($record['business_fax']).'\" style=\"margin-left: 20%;\"><br>';
        echo '<select>';
        echo '<option>Assistant</option>';
        echo '<option>Business</option>';
        echo '<option>Business 2</option>';
        echo '<option>Business Fax</option>';
        echo '<option>Callback</option>';
        echo '<option>Car</option>';
        echo '<option>Company</option>';
        echo '<option>Home</option>';
        echo '<option>Home 2</option>';
        echo '<option>Home Fax</option>';
        echo '<option>ISDN</option>';
        echo '<option selected>Mobile</option>';
        echo '<option>Other</option>';
        echo '<option>Other Fax</option>';
        echo '<option>Pager</option>';
        echo '<option>Primary</option>';
        echo '<option>Radio</option>';
        echo '<option>Telex</option>';
        echo '<option>TTY/TDD</option>';
        echo '</select>';
        echo '<input type=\"text\" value=\"'.($record['mobile_phone']).'\" style=\"margin-left: 20%;\"><br>';

        echo '<p style=\"background-color:#7A993D;\">Addresses</p>';  
        echo '<select>';            
        echo '<option  selected>Business</option>';
        echo '<option  >Home</option>';
        echo '<option  >Other</option>';
        echo '</select>'; 
        echo '<input type=\"text\" value=\"'.($record['business_street']).'\" style=\"margin-left: 26.5%;\"><br><br>';
        echo '<\/div>'; 




        echo '</body></html>';
        echo '"';
        echo ');';
        echo '}';
        echo '</script>';

        echo "<td>" . $record['middle_name'] . "</td>";      
        echo "<td>" . $record['last_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['suffix'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['company'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['department'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['job_title'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['business_street'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['business_street2'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['business_street3'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['business_city'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['business_state'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['business_postal_code'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['business_country_region'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['home_street'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['home_street2'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['home_street3'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['home_city'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['home_state'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['home_postal_code'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['home_country_region'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['other_street'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['other_street2'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['other_street3'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['other_city'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['other_state'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['other_postal_code'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['other_country_region'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['assistants_phone'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['business_fax'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['business_phone'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['business_phone2'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['callback'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['car_phone'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['company_main_phone'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['home_fax'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['home_phone'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['home_phone2'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['isdn'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['mobile_phone'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['other_fax'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['other_phone'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['pager'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['primary_phone'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['radio_phone'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['tty_tdd_phone'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['telex'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['account'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['anniversary'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['assistants_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['billing_information'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['birthday'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['business_address_po_box'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['categories'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['children'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['directory_server'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['email_address'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['email_type'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['email_display_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['email_address2'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['email_type2'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['email_display_name2'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['email_address3'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['email_type3'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['email_display_name3'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['gender'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['government_id_number'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['hobby'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['home_address_po_box'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['initials'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['internet_free_busy'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['keywords'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['language'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['location'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['managers_name'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['mileage'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['notes'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['office_location'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['organizational_id_number'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['other_address_po_box'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['priority'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['private'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['profession'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['referred_by'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $record['sensitivity'] . "</td>";

    }       
    ?>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are you sure all the 354 lines of code are needed to solve this problem?

Comment: Instead of opening a blank window and then setting the HTML you should create a seperate page and pass the querystring of ID,cell num using which you can render the page with textarea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add an id to the desired td just like

```
echo "<td id='helper'>" . $record['middle_name'] . "</td>";
```

And then use jquery

```
$('#helper').click(function(){

  var x=window.open();
x.document.open();
x.document.write('<textarea>'+$(this).val()+'</textarea>');
x.document.close();

});
```

Hope it worlks!

Comment: Thank you guys all for the fast answers.
I tried the thing with jquery, but it does not work.

So it opens new window but with empty textarea.

Seems like i can not get the value. If you guys need whole code tell me. I am just out of ideas and do not know why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:( the `window.open(...);` function) [link : w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) the simple call just opens a window with the specified url, but there is also a custom call, that enables you to specify the content

ie:

```
var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200, height=100");
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'MsgWindow'. I am 200px wide and 100px tall!</p>");
```

example taken from the above page. I guess in your situation you just have to replace the `<p>..</p>` with some generated tags (which if I read correctly you already do)